# Listen port 80 - Watching received requests - Apache

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I have a server Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache installed. I wonder if is there a way to watch, in real time, in the terminal, the requests received on port 80.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache logs all the requests in /var/log/apache2/access.log. Run the following to show them in real time:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Look at [Understanding Apache Access Log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9234699/1898852) for the meaning of the fields.